# Understanding a simple piece of JS code - Functions -

Tags: javascript

I am reading that Ninja Secrets of JS Book and seeing this part of example code:

```
    var ninja = {
      chirp: function signal(n) {                              //#1
        return n > 1 ? signal(n - 1) + "-chirp" : "chirp";
      }
    };

    var samurai = { chirp: ninja.chirp }; 

   ninja = {};
```

So I understand the first part: We have an object `ninja` and it has a method.

I understand the second part that ok now we are creating a new object called `samurai` and it has a property called `chirp`.

The part that confuses me is `ninja.chirp` part of it, what are we doing here? How is it working?

Comment: Beware that if `nina.chirp` calls certain properties of `ninja` when it's duplicated inside `samurai`, that you will get strict warnings and/or `undefined` issues when trying to access them in `samurai`, as they aren't there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It takes the value of the `chirp` property of the `ninja` object (which is a function) and assigns it to the `chirp` property of the object being constructed.

Here is a simpler example (using a string instead of a function):

```
var foo, bar;
foo = { "an": "object" };
bar = { "an": foo.an }
alert(foo.an);
alert(bar.an);
```

Comment: Thanks. And on the next line he is wiping out the ninja object, but still calling chirp works. Chrip is using ninja and ninja is wiped out, but still chirp works. So I am confused how that works too.

Comment: @user1899082 — Garbage collection won't delete the function until there are no more variables/properties holding it. Since `samurai.chirp` still holds the function, deleting `ninja` won't delete it.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this example so many times, and it is a horrible example. For starters, named function expressions are buggy in IE, but aside from that they are completely unnecessary as you can simply reference `arguments.callee`.

That aside, using a recursive function to repeat a string is just asking for trouble. The whole thing could be made so much more simply:

```
function signal(n) {
    return new Array(n+1).join("-chirp").substr(1);
}
```

Comment: While that is valid criticism of the code, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: `arguments.callee` is also deprecated from what I remember.

Comment: But I'm intrigued, how are named function expressions buggy in IE? Do they tend to cause memory leaks or something?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté This too: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs (read the whole article, it's excellent).

Comment: Thanks @Quentin that is very enlightening. IE still manages to surprise me. Also thanks bfavaretto `=]`

Answer (score 1):

In here, `chirp` its been copied to `samurai`. Than you can destroy the `ninja` object and still use the `samurai.chirp` method.

Comment: ah, it gets copied. I was thinking like C++ pointers and was confusing that how is it still working although we deleted it.

Comment: It doesn't get copied. Functions are first class objects. In JS there are only ever references to functions. The reference gets copied.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have true reference variables. This causes many confusion.